# Cross compilation: GCC ignores --sysroot

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile programs (currently avconv from libav) for a Nokia N9 phone using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc from Linux Mint's 64-bit repository. The compiler's libc version is 2.15 and the phone has libc-2.10.1. They have an incompatibility in the math library, which gives me a segfault when I compile and run the avconv program from libav.

I'd need to compile and link against the older libc version, but I haven't managed to get the `--sysroot` option to work.

I made a small test program to avoid repeatedly configuring and compiling libav.

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/CrossCompilation/NokiaN9/ -o output.sysroot hello.c
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o output.nosysroot hello.c
```

Both commands create an identical output file. This is what `hello.c` looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World! Sin = %f\n", sin(0.6451));
}
```

The strangest part is that gcc completely ignores the `--sysroot` option. If I pass a nonexisting directory to sysroot, it still produces exactly the same output binary:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/foo/bar -o output.foobar hello.c
```

It doesn't even complain about any errors. What's the problem?

Comment: Run the compiler with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v` and look at the value of **--with-sysroot**; this is the directory the compiler was built with.  If you have this directory present on your machine (maybe with a different compiler), then the `--sysroot` may not work.  What is the `gcc` version?

Comment: There is no "--with-sysroot" defined. gcc is version 4.6.3

Comment: But instead 'grep /usr/arm' finds "--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.6.3", "--includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include", "--with-headers=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include", and "--with-libs=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib".

Comment: `--with-libs` means your `gcc` is compiled without `--sysroot` support.

Answer (score 10):

since I wasted a few days messing with this before reading the comments, I'm going to post [artless noise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880339/artless-noise)'s comments as an answer:

"Run the compiler with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v` and look at the value of `--with-sysroot`; this is the directory the compiler was built with. If you have this directory present on your machine (maybe with a different compiler), then the --sysroot may not work[; and if you do *not* see `--with-sysroot` and instead see `--with-libs`, it] means your gcc is compiled without `--sysroot` support."

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: it's been a while since I messed with this, but if you have `--with-libs` instead of `--with-sysroot`, use that maybe? or download another toolchain, or build your own.