# unresolved std::__cxx11::basic_string::~basic_string and std::allocator<char>::~allocator() symbols

Tags: c++11, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile [QtWebApp](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/tutorial/index.html)  with Qt5.5.1 onto the latest RPI4-Raspbian Buster and I am encountering inexplicable GLIBCXX unresolved symbols

**What Works** : QtWebApp cross compiled from windows to armhf using qt5.5.1 binaries natively compiled on Raspbian Buster works fine with the following components

1. Toolchain : [raspberry-gcc8.3.0.exe](http://sysprogs.com/getfile/566/raspberry-gcc8.3.0.exe) installed on Windows 10.
2. Qt Binary Libs : Native compiled on RPI4 Raspbian Buster OS and
   copied over to Windows 10.
3. Command line :

   `c:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe -std=c++11 -fPIC -I. 
   {ALL QT INCLUDE DIRS}
   -IC:/SysGCC/raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/opt/vc/include 
   -g -rdynamic -funwind-tables -Woverflow
   {ALL QTWEB SOURCE FILES}
   -LC:/SysGCC/pi4/pi4qt551/lib 
   -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets 
   -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5MultimediaWidgets 
   -lQt5Network -lm -lpthread -o qtweb`

This produces an arm executable that worksfine on RPI-4.

**What fails**

When compiling natively *(which is what I want as the development env)* on RPI4 the compilation strangely fails with the following error :

`/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnnsRCD.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'`

**What I have tried** (didnt work)

**1)** Following suggestions from [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring) and passing `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` it fails with the following error :

`/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZfI5co.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSaIcED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'`

where those symbol demangles to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()` and `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()` respectively.

**2)** I also ran all the combinations `WITH/WITHOUT -std=c++11 and D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and these are the errors

```
WITH  -std=c++11, WITHOUT -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnnsRCD.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'

 WITH -std=c++11, WITH -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZfI5co.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSaIcED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'

 WITHOUT -std=c++11, WITH -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctFncwz.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSaIcED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'

 WITHOUT -std=c++11, WITHOUT -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchkJYdO.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
```

**3)** I also copied the sysroot from the [raspberry-gcc8.3.0.exe](http://sysprogs.com/getfile/566/raspberry-gcc8.3.0.exe) install on Win10 over to RPi-4 and passed that to `gcc` as its `--sysroot` location - which also fails with the `~basic_string()` unresolver error. (I dont know how to verify if the `--sysroot` had any effect though I checked that `gcc -v` output doesnt have `--with_libs` in it as suggested in a [GCC ignores --sysroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603213/cross-compilation-gcc-ignores-sysroot) post)

INFO: The command line is exactly the same on the RPI4-Buster other than  using `gcc` and not passing `-IC:/SysGCC/raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/opt/vc/include`

**Question :**
How is it that (assuming no glaring compile option mismatch ;) cross compiling with a gcc 8.3 toolchain from windows to arm-linux works but the same code base when compiled natively on raspbian buster with gcc 8.3 fails with what looks like GLIBCXX version mismatch in the Raspbian Buster OS binaries ?

I am stuck on this for 2 days now. Please suggest any other steps I can try here.

Comment: Have you tried cross-compiling from other Unix-like systems? Have you tried locally-compiling on a Linux system, with gcc 8.3.0 ?

Comment: @einpoklum not tried other unix-like env. Buster is the only linux system I tried locally compiling on. Regardless I am stumped on how an entirely native compile can have GLIBCXX conflicts... I am either being blind to something trivial or its a bug in the newish buster distro... come to think of it I guess I should post this on rpi.org also...

Comment: Maybe it's a library version mismatch somehow. Could you have more than a single libstdc++ installed? Also - have you tried adding `-lstdc++`?

Comment: @einpoklum ok, I will try `-lstdc++` and post the result. ( while wondering if its not implied by -std=c++11 ...)

Comment: Another thing to do is to example the symbols in your C++ library files, and see whether you have similar symbols in there; if you do, try to figure out what the differences are.

Comment: @einpoklum - thanks for your prompt responses - really appreciate it. I will get home in a couple of hours and post the result.  Also I havn't installed any other packages to cause more than one libstdc++ being accessed -unless its in the Buster distro.

Comment: @einpoklum "examine symbols in your C++ library files" - thats what I have been doing most of yesterday - I will repeat it in for the qt551 binaries and post what I find here . should I check any where else?

Comment: Try making your compiler be verbose, to see exactly which files it's using in practice; those are the ones to search. Otherwise use a system-wide `locate` index.

Comment: @einpoklum - amazingly `-lstdc++` resolves both basic_string and std::allocator<char> symbols... Thanks a ton ! Please post this as an answer and I will accept it. phew...

Comment: Just checking... did you invoke GCC using `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: guilty as charged ;) I used gcc but after just superficial check some time back. see response to @marc glisse below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Are you executing the compiler as `gcc` instead of `g++`? That would cause this problem. Invoke `g++`.
- Otherwise, Try adding  `-lstdc++` to your link flags.

Explanation:

The symbols are, obviously, from the C++ standard library. Under some circumstances - at the very least, when you invoke GCC using the `gcc` binary rather than `g++` - GCC compiles C++ code, but doesn't automatically link against the GNU C++ standard library. If for some reason this isn't resolved by invoking `g++`, you could try adding the `-lstdc++` flag,  which means "link against the library `libstdc++.so` or `libstdc++.a` which you should find in the library search path".

Comment: Usually, that happens to people who call `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Comment: indeed g++ resolves this without -lstdc++... - but I did check sometime back whether g++ linked to gcc as I have seen many times. While it did not, arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-8 had identical size and timestamp in /usr/bin. - but just now running a diff reports they are not identical binaries.... well ;)

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Edited accordingly.

Comment: The same thing has just happened to me when compiling with ```clang```. Adding ```-lstdc++``` to the flags solved the problem. Thanks!