Why can't Clang/lld find `__dlopen`, `__dlclose` and `__dlsym`?
Following from this question, I am trying to compile a C/C++ project that targets an old Linux system. To have the old libraries at hand, I made a copy of the target root fs, and since GCC has hardcoded the library path I cannot really cross-compile against an old version of libc. Therefore I am using Clang + lld. The point is that when linking it complains about
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable single_lidar_listener
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m32
 "/usr/bin/ld.lld" --sysroot=/home/abertulli/box-root-inst -pie -EL -z relro -X --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m armelf_linux_eabi -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -o single_lidar_listener /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/Scrt1.o /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0 -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/../../../../lib -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/lib/../lib -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/../lib -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/lib -L/home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib CMakeFiles/single_lidar_listener.dir/single_lidar.cpp.o CMakeFiles/single_lidar_listener.dir/sick_scan_xd_api_wrapper.c.o libtoojpeg.a -ldl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/crtendS.o /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __dlopen
>>> referenced by dlopen.o:(dlopen) in archive /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __dlclose
>>> referenced by dlclose.o:(.text+0x0) in archive /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __dlsym
>>> referenced by dlsym.o:(dlsym) in archive /home/abertulli/box-root-inst/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/single_lidar_listener.dir/build.make:114: single_lidar_listener] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:113: CMakeFiles/single_lidar_listener.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

Analyzing the content of libc.a as suggested in this answer, I see that these symbols are present. So why can't Clang find them? Note that sysroot is set, and the GCC installation found seems to be the correct (target-rooted) one. thanks!

toolchain file
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_DL_LIBS)

# where is the target environment located
set(root_fs_dir /home/abertulli/box-root-inst)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${root_fs_dir})
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${root_fs_dir})


# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")

set(CMAKE_LINKER       "ld.lld")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=lld -v")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}   --gcc-toolchain=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --gcc-toolchain=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr")

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY) # to avoid trying to link and execute test programs
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET   arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)


# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)


"since GCC has hardcoded the library path I cannot really cross-compile against an old version of libc." You are mistaken. This is not true. You can compile against anything you want.

Note that static linking against libc is discouraged because it almost never works as the user intends.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Sorry maybe I explained it badly: GCC is shipped configured with --with-sysroot=/, and apparently (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37464870/17789881) there's no way to make it ignore the system libraries, even if I specify a new --sysroot it will always ALSO chek the system ones, and first.

Regardless of whether -sysroot works,, the standard directories are always searched last, so you only need to add a few -I and -L options. I suspect that -sysroot actually works and whoever wrote that it doesn't is mistaken, but I cannot verify it right now.

Hmm indeed it looks like should not be shipped configured with --with-sysroot and it's a configuration bug. You can build your own using --with-sysroot because you know where sysroot is on your system. But as I said in the previous comment it should not stop you from using such build, you just need different options.

Disregard the previous commend. I checked a gcc build (13.1) configured with --with-sysroot=/, and --sysroot=/whatever works just fine and as one would expect. The linked answer is wrong.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Apparently not on my system: I compiled using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/opt/box-root-fs -o arm-sysroot main.cpp a simple test program, and the -v option lists #include <...> search starts here: [system dirs...] [sysroot dirs], so does it mean that the system dirs are checked first, I guess? And anyway when trying the produced binary on the target system I get ./arm-sysroot: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version \GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./arm-sysroot)`, so it compiled against the system libraries

Yopu may want to show the full output of the compiler with -v with and without --sysroot=... Anyway, you can always add your own directories with -I and -isystem and -L and you don't need to care about the sysroot at all.

For reference, on my system gcc says #include <...> search starts here: [gcc install dir]/include /usr/local/include [gcc install dir]/include-fixed /usr/include, and with --sysroot=/foo it says #include <...> search starts here: [gcc install dir]/include [gcc install dir]/include-fixed /foo/usr/include

@n.m.couldbeanAI you have a point, as using --sysroot -v I see that the sysroot's dirs are included with -L, but the system libraries are also linked, and I guess they take precedence?

I'm not sure why this happens. Looks like a misconfiguration to me. No system dirs on my machine. Perhaps your system dirs are somehow included twice, once as sysroot and once as something else?
